# Transform Skew-Symmetric Data to Gaussian for Machine Learning Problem?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution

I am using a GBM for a regression machine learning problem. I believe one of the assumptions for GBM and most ML algorithms (at least for regression problems) is that the y-variables are normally distributed. a histogram of my y-variables look like this:

[image: distribution of my data]

If it helps, I can provide the dput() of this vector as well. What are some good transformation functions I can use on my data to have it be more gaussian? and what are some good ways (other than looking at a histogram) to see if the transformation is a good one?

Thanks,

Comment: I don’t know the particular assumptions of GBM, but most methods, if they make a normality assumption, (1) do it for inference, not prediction (machine learning), and (2) make the assumption about the error term, not the pooled distribution of the y-values.

Comment: What does y represent? Money, time, ...? Can you share data here?

Answer (score 1):

Most methods, if they make a normality assumption;

(1) Do it for inference, not prediction (machine learning)

(2) Make the assumption about the error term, not the pooled distribution of the y-values

(3) Definitely do not make the assumption about a predictor variable, which your histogram's x-axis suggests.

If you do want to examine a normality assumption (it probably matters little for your task), you would plot the residuals of a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BoxCox transformation for converting skewed distribution to more Gaussian-like. A code excerpt:

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox, skew

xt, _ = boxcox(x)
x_skew = skew(x)
xt_skew = skew(xt)
```

You will notice a lower skewness for the transformed data.

Comment: Box-Cox often won’t play if any values are negative.